# Http form-data POST error: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found (Java)

Tags: java, html, request, http-post, form-data

## the procedure of the problem:

1. I try to get response by sending a form-data, here is the result and details from Postman(successfully got data in Postman):
2. there is an error thrown:** "<faultstring>the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found</faultstring>"**

## details of the problem:

### this is the request header

[this is the Postman request details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6RwO.png)

### this is the request body

[this is the request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQeUR.png)

### related method in HttpUtil.java below:

```
public static String PostFormdata(String url, Map<String, String> map) {
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

    for(String key:map.keySet()){
        builder.addTextBody(key, map.get(key));
    }
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setConfig(requestConfig);
        httpPost.setEntity(multipart);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        result = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

### here is my usage:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

params.put("username", "user01");
params.put("password", "abcd");
params.put("entryid", "111");
params.put("beginDate", "2023-08-01");
params.put("endDate", "2023-10-06");

Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
param.put("params", params.toString());

String result = HttpClientUtils.PostFormdata(url, param);
```

I want to get a correct result from POST request

Comment: Are you using [Spring](https://spring.io/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel, we can better redesign the API which you have posted .
Sending json kind data in header is not correct. It must be a key value pair not a json with a key called params .
Either send each data in the header or put as json in the body

Comment: could you please make an simple example of constructing the "params"?

Comment: i just construct a json string, 
`String jsonStr = JSON.toJSONString(param);`the content is: {"params":"{beginDate=2023-08-01, password=1234, endDate=2023-10-06, username=user01, entryid=283}"}

Comment: Pass this in body as an json object as this is a post call @hachi. constructing params like this in header is not a good approach . Restrain from that idea of having json object in headers

Comment: if you need to pass it in param . Pass it like header1: value1, header2:value2

Answer (score 0):

try to comment out this line:
`httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");`

or try to set boundary in `MultipartEntityBuilder` and add it to http header:

```
String boundary = "custom-boundary";
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setBoundary(boundary);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
```

Comment: i tried, but there is no correct data returned

Comment: set boundary in your MultipartEntityBuilder, and add it to header.

Comment: _set boundary in your MultipartEntityBuilder_ Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post how to do that?

Comment: get it, thanks!